# How to fix "Type Mismatch" error in For Each If statement?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to check for a pair of duplicate rows and then highlight one of them. I am doing this with a very simple If statement inside a For Each loop. The If tests whether the text in cell A1 (minus the last 4 letters) matches the text in cell A2 (minus the last 4 letters). But for some reason this If keeps throwing me a Type Mismatch error. Help!

I have tried using MsgBox to display what is on each side of the equal sign in the If statement. It displays the left side of the equal sign just fine, but throws a Type Mismatch error for the right side of the equal sign. So the problem must lie on the right side of the If statement, where I am using Offset.

```
Sub highlight_dupes()

Dim mycell As Variant

For Each mycell In Range("A:A")

If mycell = "" Then Exit Sub

'check for dupes
If Left(mycell, Len(mycell) - 4) = Left(mycell.Offset(1, 0), Len((mycell.Offset(1, 0)) - 4)) Then

'highlight dupes
Rows(mycell.Row).Interior.Color = vbRed

End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Consider what happens when `myCell` gets to an empty cell.

Comment: Also consider what happens when `myCell` is the last cell in column A. Can you `Offset(1, 0)`?

Comment: BTW, this will be horribly slow. Reduce the search range to only rows containing data

Comment: You might be interested in trying the "highlight duplicates" conditional formatting rule, which would be much more efficient than this code.

Comment: I left this out, but i have If mycell = "" Then Exit Sub

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Too many parentheses...in the case given, you are trying to subtract 4 from the cell before calculating the length, thereby causing the mismatch.

```
If Left(mycell, Len(mycell) - 4) = Left(mycell.Offset(1, 0), Len((mycell.Offset(1, 0)) - 4)) Then
```

should be...

```
If Left(mycell, Len(mycell) - 4) = Left(mycell.Offset(1, 0), Len(mycell.Offset(1, 0)) - 4) Then
```

Comment: `(mycell.Offset(1, 0))` is let-coercing a `Range` and getting its value via an implicit call to `Range.[_Default]`. `mycell.Offset(1, 0)` is let-coercing a `Range` and getting its value via an implicit call to `Range.[_Default]` all the same - these two statements are exactly the same.

Comment: @mathieuguindon Not the same.  In one case the 4 is being subtracted before calculating the length, in the other it calculates the length, then subtracts the 4.

Comment: @DarrellH would you mind clarifying that in the answer itself? Because eye-diffing the two instructions is mind-boggling. But yes, I see it now - thanks! (upvoted)